# Git - Getting the hash value of a Tree by filename

Tags: git

Lets say i have a file called example.rb that has been committed. What i need to do is find the SHA-1 hash of the tree object that represents the base directory of the project at the time of that commit.

What i do first is

```
git ls-files -s example.rb
```

which gives me

```
100755 ee9e1ee0ed2cb17f66fba5331e7c953bd1530b55 0   example.rb
```

But how do i get the Tree hash from there?

If i use

```
git cat-file -p ee9e1ee0ed2cb17f66fba5331e7c953bd1530b55
```

It just gives me the actual file rather than the meta data for the file which i'm after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with `ls-files`:  `ls-files` works on the *index* which does not actually contain folders.  (The tree structure is built when you commit.)

But since you're looking for a tree in a commit, you can use `ls-tree` instead:

```
git ls-tree -d HEAD <dir_path>
```